# How to keep previous enterd data inJtables in swing

Tags: jtable

While making a swing application, I am taking a data from a frame and on submit displaying the data in the form of Jtable.

How can I store the Previous values in the table and when the next time user enters the data it has to show both the data in the table?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us the code you haver tried so far @shiva0987

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask